# Azure App Service : deployment using pipelines: EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-app-service-plans

## Introduction

Hi, I am deploying a Python-Flask application on the Azure App Service for months.

Today I got the following error message while running my pipeline running on Microsoft DevOps:

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: **[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/8d876019152941b/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy-1.18.1.dist-info'**

I got the error on other apps stored on the same Plan. All my apps can't be updated anymore

## what did I try

I created a new app and deployed the same code.
I got the same error :

> Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/REDACTED.zip (246.59 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted

> No space left on device

> ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.

**The plan states that my threshold quota is 10 Gb and that I use 936Mb or 9% of my quota !**

## Using 'df-h' by using Kundu Bash

```
> Filesystem   Size   Used Avail Use%   Mounted on
> none         29G    27G  0     100%   /
> tmpfs        64M     0   64M   0%     /dev
> tmpfs        953M     0  953M  0%     /sys/fs/cgroup
> shm          62M     0   62M   0%     /dev/shm
> //REDACTED/  1000G  9.7G 991G  1% /home
> /dev/sda1    27G    8.6G 18G   34%    /appsvctmp
> /dev/loop6p1 29G    27G  0     100%   /etc/hosts
> udev 920M    0      920M       0%     /dev/tty
> tmpfs 953M   0      953M       0%     /proc/acpi
> tmpfs 953M   0      953M       0%     /proc/scsi
> tmpfs 953M   0      953M       0%     /sys/firmware
```

## The question

What should I do to work again?

I can't access the /dev/loop6p1 directory (what is it?) and delete files

## the Azure pipelines logs

```
> 2020-10-21 ##[section]Starting: Deploy Azure Web App : www.alt-f1.be
> 2020-10-21 ==============================================================================
> 2020-10-21 Task         : Azure Web App
> 2020-10-21 Description  : Deploy an Azure Web App for Linux or Windows
> 2020-10-21 Version      : 1.168.3
> 2020-10-21 Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> 2020-10-21 Help         : https://aka.ms/azurewebapptroubleshooting
> 2020-10-21 ==============================================================================
> 2020-10-21 Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'www.alt-f1.be'
> 2020-10-21 Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
> 2020-10-21 Updating submodules.
> 2020-10-21 Preparing deployment for commit id '1ea14e5515'.
> 2020-10-21 Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
> 2020-10-21 Running oryx build...
> 2020-10-21 Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.8 -i /tmp/8d876019152941b -p compress_virtualenv=tar-gz -p virtualenv_name=antenv --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log 
> 2020-10-21 Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
> 2020-10-21 You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
> 2020-10-21 
> 2020-10-21 Oryx Version: 0.2.20200917.1, Commit: 59deb778658a124cb74ea8e2c8f39fa87abcc9d9, ReleaseTagName: 20200917.1
> 2020-10-21 
> 2020-10-21 Build Operation ID: |18pOsx/PQ8Y=.d0555319_
> 2020-10-21 Repository Commit : 1ea14e5515974a80bdcdc28eac749d4f
> 2020-10-21 
> 2020-10-21 Detecting platforms...
> 2020-10-21 Detected following platforms:
> 2020-10-21   nodejs: 12.18.3
> 2020-10-21   python: 3.8.5
> 2020-10-21 
> 2020-10-21 Using intermediate directory '/tmp/8d876019152941b'.
> 2020-10-21 
> 2020-10-21 Copying files to the intermediate directory...
> 2020-10-21 Done in 6 sec(s).
> 2020-10-21 
> 2020-10-21 Source directory     : /tmp/8d876019152941b
> 2020-10-21 Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
> 2020-10-21 
> 2020-10-21 Python Version: /opt/python/3.8.5/bin/python3.8
> 2020-10-21 Python Virtual Environment: antenv
> 2020-10-21 Creating virtual environment...
> 2020-10-21 Activating virtual environment...
> 2020-10-21 Running pip install...
> 2020-10-21 [20:41:33+0000] Collecting altf1be_helpers==2.1.4
> 2020-10-21 [20:41:33+0000]   Downloading altf1be_helpers-2.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
...

> 2020-10-21 [20:44:13+0000] Installing collected packages: numpy, six, python-dateutil, pytz, pandas, certifi, urllib3, idna, chardet, requests, isodate, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, msrest, azure-core, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, azure-storage-blob, Unidecode, altf1be-helpers, attrs, Babel, pyparsing, packaging, > webencodings, bleach, cachelib, click, dash-core-components, dash-html-components, dash-table, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, Flask, brotli, Flask-Compress, retrying, plotly, dash-renderer, future, dash, docopt, docutils, Flask-Babel, Flask-Session, SQLAlchemy, Flask-SQLAlchemy, gunicorn, zipp, importlib-metadata, jeepney, > SecretStorage, keyring, more-itertools, yarg, pipreqs, pkginfo, pluggy, py, Pygments, pyodbc, pyopenssl, wcwidth, pytest, python-dotenv, readme-renderer, requests-toolbelt, starkbank-ecdsa, python-http-client, sendgrid, tqdm, twine, WTForms, xlrd, XlsxWriter
> 2020-10-21 ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/8d876019152941b/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy-1.18.1.dist-info'
> 2020-10-21 
> 2020-10-21 WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2.4 is available.
> 2020-10-21 You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/8d876019152941b/antenv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
> 2020-10-21 ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/8d876019152941b/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy-1.18.1.dist-info'\n\nWARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2.4 is available.\nYou should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/> 8d876019152941b/antenv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.8 -i /tmp/8d876019152941b -p compress_virtualenv=tar-gz -p virtualenv_name=antenv --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log 
> 2020-10-21 ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
> 2020-10-21 ##[error]To debug further please check Kudu stack trace URL : https://$www.alt-f1.be:***@www.alt-f1.be.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace
> 2020-10-21 ##[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
> 2020-10-21 Successfully updated deployment History at https://www.alt-f1.be.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/2571603313079929
> 2020-10-21 App Service Application URL: https://www.alt-f1.be.azurewebsites.net
> 2020-10-21 ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure Web App : www.alt-f1.be
```

## Conclusion

My plan is completely blocked. It is not possible to deploy any version of my code anymore.

Comment: What tier do you use? Is it Windows or Linux plan?

Comment: I saw Running pip install in your deployment log, This makes me a little confused, maybe I don't know much about python. So do you mind sharing how your release pipeline is configured?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I use the B1 plan

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT running pip install is like running Nuget : you need to install the dependencies otherwise the app crashes miserably ;-)

Comment: @Abdelkrim, Microsoft-hosted agents provides 10 GB of storage for your source and build outputs -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations

All the WebApps under Azure App Service plan shares resources.

Comment: @Abdelkrim, Looks like you're review the App Service Plan storage space vs Hosted agents limitation.  Also, Linux apps in App Service run in their own containers. No access to the host operating system is allowed, you do have root access to the container. Likewise, for apps running in Windows containers, you have administrative access to the container but no access to the host operating system.

Comment: @Abdelkrim, If your source code and build outputs are more then 10GB, I suggest you to run your build using the Self Hosted Agent.
 

For the python storage issue, you may try clearing the cache using the below command once and see if that helps.



pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow-gpu

Comment: @Abdelkrim, Also, the error is likely for hitting the temp  -This a partition separate from your disk space. It is used for docker operations like unpacking/writing that require a temporary directory to offload files during processing.

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files

When the integrated pipeline is used, we go though webengine code (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2013/06/19/uploading-large-file-to-iis-7-5-or-8-using-file-input-element/) which doesn't support more than 2 GB content-length.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing the same issue and this is due because if you have enabled  "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT" or "ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD" and this uses tmp folder for deployment in which it is mounted on / directory and you don't have space to the deployment.

The best solution could be to upgrade the App service plan and that will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

@Abdelkrim, Microsoft-hosted agents provides 10 GB of storage for your source and build outputs- [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations) - All the WebApps under Azure App Service plan shares resources.

If your source code and build outputs are more then 10GB, I suggest you to run your build using the **Self Hosted Agent**. For the python storage issue, you may try clearing the cache using the below command once and see if that helps.
--> pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow-gpu

Also just to isolate, the error is likely for [hitting the temp](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files) (in your table shows 100% usage) -This a partition separate from your disk space. It is used for docker operations like unpacking/writing that require a temporary directory to offload files during processing.
-When the integrated pipeline is used, it goes though webengine code which doesn't support more than [2 GB content-length](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/friis/uploading-large-file-to-iis-7-5-or-8-using-file-input-element).

In regards to drive access: - Looks like you're reviewing the App Service Plan storage space vs Hosted agents limitation. Also, Linux apps in App Service run in their own containers. No access to the host operating system is allowed, you do have root access to the container. Likewise, for apps running in Windows containers, you have administrative access to the container but no access to the host operating system.

<<Added as an answer;from comments>>

Comment: dear @ajaykumar-msft

I understand what you are saying but this is a bug in the Azure Architecture!

I can't deploy any more apps on my B1 plan!

Could you escalate the issue?

Comment: dear @ajaykumar-msft

Why should I install tensorflow-gpu into my project? 

Again, this is insane that Microsoft believes that I need to install libraries that have nothing to do with my business

Comment: Apologies for any confusion here. I'd shared more details in the comment section. I have tried similar deployments on B1 plan and it is fine. You have stated you'd deployed the new app, could you please confirm, if it was in a new B1 App Service Plan or the existing B1 plan. Just to isolate and if's feasible, kindly scale-up to Standard Plan S1, and then try (after the test, you may immediately scale-down to B1).

Comment: As mentioned in this article -if you use "df", the disk space you see won't reflect that quota  - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/ba-p/392472

Also, you can check your limit and usage in portal by going to "Diagnose and solve problems" section of your App Service blade, selecting "Best Practices", "Best Practices for Availability, Performance", and then "Temp File Usage On Workers". Please note that the displayed usage and limits are per worker, and are aggregated across all apps in the same app service plan.

Comment: @ajakumar-msft I have moved my 'app service' into another B1 plan. Now it works again because there is only one app into the plan.

But now, I pay a new Plan because the previous plan is not correctly functioning !

Comment: dear @ajakumar-msft : here is the result of 'temp file usage on workers' : 

Failed to retrieve quota utilization for workers hosting this site. Kindly ensure that the site has traffic during the selected timeframe.